# Are holder space dense in $L^p$ ? or in Schwarz space?

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I recall that $f\in \mathcal C^\alpha ([0,1[)$ where $\alpha \in (0,1)$ if $$[f]_\alpha :=\sup_{x,y\in\mathbb [0,1[}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha }<\infty .$$

Does those space are dense in $L^p$ space ? Or in Schwarz space ? I'm asking this question because they use this result at the beginning of the proof page 3 [here.](http://jahia-prod.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/pde/files/cours/2015-2016/harmonic%20analysis/Lecture2_1.pdf)

If yes, can we generalize this to $\mathbb R^n$ ? i.e. Is $\mathcal C^\alpha (\mathbb R^n)$ dense in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ ?

Comment: I think the answer to your question follows from the facts that the compactly supported smooth functions are dense in $L^p$ and that smooth functions are Hölder continuous.